# Is there a html class for changing text color in material design lite?

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

Is there a html class for changing text-color or opacity of a custom mdl element in material design lite? I would like to use it, didn't find anything about this in the official documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You can always change the color:

.docs-text-styling p {
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

Comment: Yes, but i thought it also has some of its own classes for this. I found this for example on a site: "mdl-color-text--{color-name}-{shade}" http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learning-material-design-lite-customizing--cms-24669 . It's working, but in the official documentation it doesn't mention about it, or at least i haven't found it.

Are there any helper classes, like bootstrap has?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all the classes available under mdl-color--*color*-*intensity* are available as mdl-color-text--*color*-*intensity*.

Unfortunately this isn't in the documentation but you can find the complete list in the css included.